# Triggering an action when a specific volume is connected

Tags: 12.10, automount, keepass

I have a USB key that contains my keepass2 password database and I'd like to perform some actions when it is plugged into my computer, namely:

- Auto-mount it to some specific location
- When the mounting is done properly, launching keepass2 on the password database file

Simple tasks I guess, but I can't find how to do that.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, and it auto-mounts the device as a "media usb-key" and tries to open the images on it (even though there are none).

What is the best way to do that and to disable the ubuntu auto-mounting (so it doesn't conflict) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `udev`, you must write rules in separate file and put them to `/etc/udev/rules.d`

For example this rule describes udev to run `/path/to/mount/script` when usb is mounted and `/path/to/umount/script` when umounted.

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]1", RUN+="/path/to/mount/script", OPTIONS="last_rule"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]1", RUN+="/path/to/umount/script"
```

[Here](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) you can read complete manual.